# Bad CSS3 translateZ in Chrome - puts newest elements in front of the furthest ones

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, 3d

Testing CSS3 3D performance. Made a [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sjvgn/), which generates a rotating cubes with translateZ in range from -1 to -10000.
Works ok in firefox, but in chrome the newest elements are always on top of the oldest/closest ones.

Other thing - after multiple cubes, in firefox the cube faces became see-trough/change their depth value. The same happens in chrome, except those faces become invisible.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotate in hover doesn't work in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379971/rotate-in-hover-doesnt-work-in-chrome)

Comment: work perfect in the last version of google chrome. Maybe close the answer

Comment: Nope, problem still persists.